# Rails Controllers: Call another action of the same controller conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

I need to call one of two other controller actions from a first one (`UsersController#show`) based on an `if-else`-condition, which I also defined as methods of the controller and wherein I have put a `render` directive.

Is there another way than `redirect_to action: "profile"` because then I get the error message

```
No route matches {:action=>"profile", :controller=>"users", :id=>"1"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the appropriate route if you want to do a redirect

```rb
# routes.rb
get 'users/profile/:id' => 'users#profile', as: :profile
```

Comment: Hello

actually I don't want a proper redirect, I just want to call either controller-action #b or #c from #a depending on whether some condition in #a is true or not.

Cheers !

Comment: Just call them like any other method then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
def show
  return action_b if your_condition?

  action_c
end
```

Comment: My dear Sachin Singh, isn't it just possible to call one controller action of the same controller from another controller-action? Cheers !